# Custom bearing roatation for mapview

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

Hi I have a Map application where I used google maps, everything works fine and now I want to change the bearing of the mapView when I click a button like the Uber app when you confirm a ride, the map continues to change bearing until a driver is found the it returns to default and when there is no driver, it returns to default. Currently I am able to just rotate the mapView as the use rotates his device but if the user does not, the bearing does not change on it's own.

> so My question is how how to create custom bearings

Below is how I am able to rotate the mapView when a user rotates his device

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading) {

    mapView.animate(toBearing: newHeading.magneticHeading)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just introduce property and store the new value from the start. Then, when user pushes the button rotate the map from stored value.

```
    var knownHeading: CLHeading
    var buttonPushed = false

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading) {
        if buttonPushed {
            mapView.animate(toBearing: newHeading.magneticHeading)
        } else {
            knownHeading = newHeading
        }
    }

    @IBAction func buttonPushed() {
        mapView.animate(toBearing: knownHeading.magneticHeading)
        buttonPushed = true

        //your other code here
    }
```